# Openshift - port to use on deployment

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have the following `start.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('static'));

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

In my NodeJs application on Openshift. However, when I run `rhc tail-a app-name`
I can see that there is an error of :

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080

I've tried 80 and 443, and received those errors:

> Error: listen EACCESS 0.0.0.0:443

Or `80`

Which port should I use as default on my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx),
Nginx (pronounced "engine x") is a web server. It can act as a reverse proxy server for HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, POP3, and IMAP protocols, as well as a load balancer and an HTTP cache.

It isn't good practice to run your application with root privileges or directly run your application on port 80 and your port 8080 is in use. Try different port and use reverse proxy.

But if you want to run on port 80 or 443, run your application with root privileges.